# looping over div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop over divs and insert div items dynamically but its just inserting only one div item into the html page.
this is my code :

```
     function loadArticles ()      {        
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();   
     request.onreadystatechange = function (){   
         if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){   
          var articles = document.getElementById('articles');  
            if (request.status === 200) {  
              var articleData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  
                for (var i=0; i< articleData.length; i++) {  
         var content = `<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
             <div class="post-preview">
                  <a href="/${articleData[i].title}">
                      <h2 class="post-title">
                       ${articleData[i].heading}</h2>
                       <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                       ${articleData[i].subtitle}</h3>
                      </a>
       <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">${articleData[i].author}</a> on Date ${articleData.date[i].toDateString()}</p>
       </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`;
            }
            articles.innerHTML = content;
        } else {
            articles.innerHTML('Oops! Could not load all articles!')
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnerHtml is a string. So your code will *override* the content i times. You need to add to the string:

```
articles.innerHTML+=content;
```

And this line needs to be inside of the for loop...

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the content every loop step by declaring content inside the loop. You should declare `content` outside of the loop then assign it post loop.

```
var content = '';

for (var i=0; i< articleData.length; i++) {  
  content += `<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="post-preview">
          <a href="/${articleData[i].title}">
            <h2 class="post-title">
              ${articleData[i].heading}</h2>
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
              ${articleData[i].subtitle}</h3>
          </a>
          <p class="post-meta">
            Posted by <a href="#">${articleData[i].author}</a> 
            on Date ${articleData.date[i].toDateString()}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
}

articles.innerHtml = content;
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy like this:

```
        }
            articles.innerHTML += content;
        } else {
            articles.innerHTML ='Oops! Could not load all articles!';
        }
```

First thing you are over write the existing  data .so use `+`.It will append the data

And  second is a `syntax error` `innerHTML=` instead of `innerHTML()`

```
   function loadArticles ()      {        
     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();   
     request.onreadystatechange = function (){   
         if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){   
          var articles = document.getElementById('articles');  
            if (request.status === 200) {  
              var articleData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  
                for (var i=0; i< articleData.length; i++) {  
         var content = `<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
             <div class="post-preview">
                  <a href="/${articleData[i].title}">
                      <h2 class="post-title">
                       ${articleData[i].heading}</h2>
                       <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                       ${articleData[i].subtitle}</h3>
                      </a>
       <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">${articleData[i].author}</a> on Date ${articleData.date[i].toDateString()}</p>
       </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`;
            }
            articles.innerHTML += content;
        } else {
            articles.innerHTML ='Oops! Could not load all articles!';
        }
    }
};
```